# Float left and float right not working + sub-menu positioned under first UL item?

Tags: html, css

Been learning CSS and HTML quite a lot lately, and although I already know about stuff like float, positioning, margins, padding, etc, for some reason splitting up these 2 things are not working...

And also my submenu is a bit wrong, refer to the image below:

[image]

As you can see under the menu, when I hover over team, the sub-menu displays under home? Not sure why, this was not a problem before I moved the menu bar.

Secondly, as you can see the "hello" and "limpsum, etc" text is not under "COMPANY" even though, i told it to float to the left, and likewise the "blog image" should be displayed under contact

Basically, COMPANY + menu are both in a container (nav) and hello/limsum + blog image, are both under their own container. both are 100% width, hello/limsum are floated to the left, blog image to the right, but their position just doesnt change.

```css
/*
 Business Website
 Author: Joel Male;
 Date Started: 20/06/2015;
 Date Finished: **;
*/

/* 
 ////////////////////////////////////
 /////////// WEB STUFF //////////////
 ////////////////////////////////////
*/

@font-face {
 font-family: BebasFont;
 src: url("bebas-font.ttf");
}

/* 
 ////////////////////////////////////
 ////// HANDLE DEFAULT MARKUPS //////
 ////////////////////////////////////
*/

body {
 background-color: #666;
 color: #000305;
 font-size: 87.5%;
 font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
 line-height: 1.5;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {

}

a:hover, a:active {

}

/* 
 ////////////////////////////////////
 //// HANDLE HEADER/CONTAINER ///////
 ////////////////////////////////////
*/

header {
 margin: 0 auto; /* Centers the page */
 width: 100%;
 clear: both; /* Nothing floats on the page */
}

.content {
 width: 70%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

/* 
 ////////////////////////////////////
 ////// HANDLE MAINHEADER HERE //////
 ////////////////////////////////////
*/

.mainheader {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #022930;
 height: 300px;
}

.mainheader nav {
 padding-top: 2%;
 height: 40px;
}

.mainheader nav h1 {
 color: white;
 font-family: 'BebasFont';
 margin-top: -12px;
 float: left;
 padding-left: 15%;
 font-size: 40px;
}

.mainheader nav ul {
 padding-right: 15%;
 float: right;
 padding-left: 0; /* THIS REMOVES THE PADDING BETWEEN NAV AND HOME */
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainheader nav ul li {
 font-family: 'BebasFont';
 position: relative;
 display: inline;
}

.mainheader nav ul li ul {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 160%;
}

.mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited {
 color: #FFF;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 25px;
 height: 20px;
}

.mainheader nav a:hover, .mainheader nav a:active,
.mainheader nav .active a:link, .mainheader nav .active a:visited {
 background-color: #CF5C3F;
 text-shadow: none;
}

.mainheader nav ul li a {
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainheader .subheader {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
}

.mainheader .subheader .left-content {
 padding-top: 3%;
 float: left;
 width: 30%;
}

.mainheader .subheader .left-content h1 {
 font-family: 'BebasFont';
 color: #FFF;
}

.mainheader .subheader .right-content{
 float: right;
 width: 30%;
 height: 200px;
}

/* 
 ////////////////////////////////////
 //// HANDLE THE DROP DOWN MENUS ////
 ////////////////////////////////////
*/

.mainheader nav ul li:hover ul {
 display: block; /* THIS SHOULD HANDLE THE SHOWING OF THE MENU */
 z-index: 10;
 padding-right: 0;
}


.mainheader nav ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #666;
}

.mainheader nav ul ul li {
 display: block;
 padding-right: 0;
 min-width: 178px;
}

.mainheader nav ul ul li:hover {
 background-color: #CF5C3F;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

/* 
 ////////////////////////////////////
 /////// HANDLE THE SLOGAN TEXT /////
 ////////////////////////////////////
*/

.subheader {
 height: 130px;
}

.subheader .slogan-wrapper {
 float: left;
 width: 45%;
 padding-top: 4%;
 padding-left: 15%;
}

.subheader p b i {
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #CF5C3F;
}

.subheader .logo-wrapper {
 float: right;
 margin-top: -5px;
 padding-right: 15%;
}

.subheader img {
 width: 160px;
 height: 160px;
}

/* 
 ////////////////////////////////////
 //// HANDLE THE FIRST SECTION //////
 ////////////////////////////////////
*/

.firstsection {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 line-height: 25px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.firstsection .firstarticle {
 background-color: #FFF;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 2% 0%;
 margin-top: 2.8%;
 height: 220px;
 background-color: #CCC; /* THIS CHANGES THE BACKGROUND COLOR OF THE TOP CONTENT BACKGROUND */
}

.firstsection .firstarticle .image-wrapper {
 width: 32%;
 padding-left: 2%;
 float: left;
}

.firstsection .firstarticle h1 {
 margin-top: 0;
}

.firstsection .firstarticle .leftcontent {
 width: 26%;
 float: left;
}

.firstsection .firstarticle .leftcontent a {
 color: #07bac1;
}

.firstsection .firstarticle .leftcontent a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.firstsection .firstarticle .rightcontent {
 padding-right: 2%;
 width: 26%;
 float: right;
}

.firstsection .firstarticle .rightcontent img {
 padding-right: 3%;
}

.firstsection .firstarticle .rightcontent i {
 font-style: italic;
 color: #999;
 font-size: 85%;
}

/* 
 ////////////////////////////////////
 //////// HANDLE THE FOOTER /////////
 ////////////////////////////////////
*/

.mainfooter {
 width: 100%;
 height: 140px;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 margin-top: 2%;
 background-color: #666;
 color: white;
}
.mainfooter a {
 color: #FFF;
}

.mainfooter .top-row {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 line-height: 5px;
}

.mainfooter .top-row h1 {
 padding-top: 1%;
 padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.mainfooter .top-row .leftrow {
 padding-left: 15%;
 padding-top: 5%;
 float: left;
}

.mainfooter .top-row .right-leftside {
 width: 300px;
 float: right;
}

.mainfooter .top-row .right-rightside {
 width: 300px;
 padding-right: 7%;
 float: right;
}

/* 
 ////////////////////////////////////
 /// HANDLE PHONE/SMALLER SCREENS ///
 ////////////////////////////////////
*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 600px)
{
 .body {
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 95%;
 }

 .mainheader img {
  width: 30%;
 }

 .mainheader nav {
  background: #666;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 }

 .mainheader nav ul {
  list-style: none; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 0;
 }

 .mainheader nav li {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
 }

 .mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited {
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 .mainheader nav a:active,
 .mainheader nav .active a:link, .mainheader nav .active a:visited {
  background: #CF5C3F;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none !important;
 }

 .mainheader nav li a {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 }

 .content {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2%;
 }

 .top-content {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3% 5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
 }

 .bottom-content {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3% 5%;
  margin-top: 2px;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title> Computer Company </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body onLoad="slideA()">

 <header>
  <div class="mainheader">
   <nav>
    <h1>Company</h1>
    <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Solutions & Services</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Networking</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Website</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Home Computers</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Servers</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Team</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Founder</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Graphics</a></li>
      </ul></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>

   <div class="subheader">
    <div class="left-content">
     <h1>Hello!</h1>

     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="right-content">
     <img src="images/logo.jpg"/>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </header>

 <div class="subheader">
  <div class="slogan-wrapper">
   <p><b><i>An incredibly efficient I.T agency</i></b></p>
  </div>
  <div class="logo-wrapper">
   <img src="images/logo.jpg"/>
  </div>
 </div>


<div class="content">

 <div class="firstsection">
   <article class="firstarticle">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
     <img src="images/computer.jpeg"/>
    </div>
    <content class="leftcontent">
     <h1>Efficient, Affordable, Reliable</h1>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.</p>
     <p><a href="#">› Contact us</a></p>
    </content>
    <content class="rightcontent">
     <h1>Latest Feedback</h1>
     <p><img src="images/plus.gif"/>Solved my problem quickly and efficiently! <i>- Melissa, QLD</i></p>
     <p><img src="images/plus.gif"/>Called Joel to organize an appointment, he came over and fixed the problem the same day!<i>- Zac, QLD </i></p>
    </content>
   </article>
 </div>

</div>


<footer class="mainfooter">
 <div class="top-row">

  <p class="leftrow"> &copy; 2015 <a href="index.html">Computer Company</a></p>

  <div class="right-rightside">
   <h1>Contact</h1>
   <p>Joel Male @</p>
   <p>Mobile</p>
   <p>Email</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-leftside">
   <h1>Opening Hours</h1>
   <p>Monday - Friday: 9am - 5pm</p>
   <p>Saturday: 10am - 4pm</p>
   <p>Sunday: Closed</p>
   <p>Public Holidays: Closed</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Might it have something to do with position? I haven't dealt with these, so i don't know what absolute, relative, etc do :(

thank you :(

Edit: i realized the pastebin code was out of date, and html, so i updated them. also reflecting the first answers suggested changes.

Comment: please give the link of site if you have or jsfiddle if possible?

Comment: It's localhosted at the moment sorry :(

Comment: please check my final ans..ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your `nav ul li` relative position: `poisition:relative` and your `nav ul li ul` should have the following rules:

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:27px; /* so it will bedirectly underneath */
```

Finally, to get the hovering working, use `nav ul li:hover>a` selector for the hover effect, instead of `nav ul li a:hover`.

**Changed code:**

```
.mainheader nav ul li {
  font-family: 'BebasFont';
  display: inline;
  z-index: -10px;
  position:relative; /* added this */
}

.mainheader nav li:hover>a, /*changed this from .mainheader nav li a:hover */
.mainheader nav a:active,
.mainheader nav .active a:link,
.mainheader nav .active a:visited {
  background-color: #CF5C3F;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.mainheader nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  /* THIS SHOULD HANDLE THE SHOWING OF THE MENU */
  z-index: 10;
  padding-right: 0;
  /*NEW STUFF*/
  position:absolute;
  top:27px;
  left:0;
  /*END OF NEW STUFF*/
}
```

Working demo:

```css
/*
        Business Website
        Author: Joel Male;
        Date Started: 20/06/2015;
        Date Finished: **;
*/

/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        /////////// WEB STUFF //////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

@font-face {
  font-family: BebasFont;
  src: url("bebas-font.ttf");
}
/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        ////// HANDLE DEFAULT MARKUPS //////
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

body {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #000305;
  font-size: 87.5%;
  font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:link,
a:visited {} a:hover,
a:active {}
/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        //// HANDLE HEADER/CONTAINER ///////
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Centers the page */
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  /* Nothing floats on the page */
}
.content {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        ////// HANDLE MAINHEADER HERE //////
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

.mainheader {
  width: 100%;
}
.mainheader nav {
  padding-right: 15%;
  background-color: #022930;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 2%;
}
.mainheader nav h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'BebasFont';
  margin-top: -12px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15%;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.mainheader nav ul {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 0;
  /* THIS REMOVES THE PADDING BETWEEN NAV AND HOME */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.mainheader nav ul li {
  font-family: 'BebasFont';
  display: inline;
  z-index: -10px;
  position:relative; /* added this */
}
.mainheader nav a:link,
.mainheader nav a:visited {
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  height: 20px;
}
.mainheader nav li:hover>a, /*changed this from .mainheader nav li a:hover */
.mainheader nav a:active,
.mainheader nav .active a:link,
.mainheader nav .active a:visited {
  background-color: #CF5C3F;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.mainheader nav ul li a {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        //// HANDLE THE DROP DOWN MENUS ////
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

.mainheader nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  /* THIS SHOULD HANDLE THE SHOWING OF THE MENU */
  z-index: 10;
  padding-right: 0;
  /*NEW STUFF*/
  position:absolute;
  top:27px;
  left:0;
  /*END OF NEW STUFF*/
}
.mainheader nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #666;
}
.mainheader nav ul ul li {
  display: block;
  padding-right: 0;
  min-width: 178px;
}
.mainheader nav ul ul li:hover {
  background-color: #CF5C3F;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        // HANDLE THE CONTACT RIGHT SIDE ///
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

.mainheader p {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 18%;
  color: #FFF;
}
.mainheader p b {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        /////// HANDLE THE SLOGAN TEXT /////
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

.subheader {
  height: 130px;
}
.subheader .slogan-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  padding-top: 4%;
  padding-left: 15%;
}
.subheader p b i {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #CF5C3F;
}
.subheader .logo-wrapper {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -5px;
  padding-right: 15%;
}
.subheader img {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
}
/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        //// HANDLE THE FIRST SECTION //////
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

.firstsection {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.firstsection .firstarticle {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2% 0%;
  margin-top: 2.8%;
  height: 220px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  /* THIS CHANGES THE BACKGROUND COLOR OF THE TOP CONTENT BACKGROUND */
}
.firstsection .firstarticle .image-wrapper {
  width: 32%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  float: left;
}
.firstsection .firstarticle h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.firstsection .firstarticle .leftcontent {
  width: 26%;
  float: left;
}
.firstsection .firstarticle .leftcontent a {
  color: #07bac1;
}
.firstsection .firstarticle .leftcontent a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.firstsection .firstarticle .rightcontent {
  padding-right: 2%;
  width: 26%;
  float: right;
}
.firstsection .firstarticle .rightcontent img {
  padding-right: 3%;
}
.firstsection .firstarticle .rightcontent i {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 85%;
}
/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        //////// HANDLE THE FOOTER /////////
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

.mainfooter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
.mainfooter a {
  color: #FFF;
}
.mainfooter .top-row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.mainfooter .top-row h1 {
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}
.mainfooter .top-row .leftrow {
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  float: left;
}
.mainfooter .top-row .right-leftside {
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
}
.mainfooter .top-row .right-rightside {
  width: 300px;
  padding-right: 7%;
  float: right;
}
/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        /// HANDLE PHONE/SMALLER SCREENS ///
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 600px) {
  .body {
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 95%;
  }
  .mainheader img {
    width: 30%;
  }
  .mainheader nav {
    background: #666;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .mainheader nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .mainheader nav li {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
  }
  .mainheader nav a:link,
  .mainheader nav a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .mainheader nav a:active,
  .mainheader nav .active a:link,
  .mainheader nav .active a:visited {
    background: #CF5C3F;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none !important;
  }
  .mainheader nav li a {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .content {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2%;
  }
  .top-content {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3% 5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
  }
  .bottom-content {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3% 5%;
    margin-top: 2px;
  }
}

.mainheader nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  /* THIS SHOULD HANDLE THE SHOWING OF THE MENU */
  z-index: 10;
  padding-right: 0;
  /*NEW STUFF*/
  position:absolute;
  top:27px;
  left:0;
  /*END OF NEW STUFF*/
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="mainheader">
    <nav>
      <h1>Company</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Solutions & Services</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Internet</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Networking</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Website</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Home Computers</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Servers</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Founder</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Graphics</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!--<p class="mainheader-phone"> Call Joel at <b>0468-575-424</b> </p>-->
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="subheader">
  <div class="slogan-wrapper">
    <p><b><i>An incredibly efficient I.T agency</i></b>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="logo-wrapper">
    <img src="images/logo.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>


<div class="content">

  <div class="firstsection">
    <article class="firstarticle">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="images/computer.jpeg" />
      </div>
      <content class="leftcontent">
        <h1>Efficient, Affordable, Reliable</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
          ullamco laboris nisi. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.</p>
        <p><a href="#">› Contact us</a>
        </p>
      </content>
      <content class="rightcontent">
        <h1>Latest Feedback</h1>
        <p>
          <img src="images/plus.gif" />Solved my problem quickly and efficiently! <i>- Melissa, QLD</i>
        </p>
        <p>
          <img src="images/plus.gif" />Called Joel to organize an appointment, he came over and fixed the problem the same day!<i>- Zac, QLD </i>
        </p>
      </content>
    </article>
  </div>

</div>


<footer class="mainfooter">
  <div class="top-row">

    <p class="leftrow">&copy; 2015 <a href="index.html">Computer Company</a>
    </p>

    <div class="right-rightside">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      <p>Joel Male @</p>
      <p>Mobile</p>
      <p>Email</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-leftside">
      <h1>Opening Hours</h1>
      <p>Monday - Friday: 9am - 5pm</p>
      <p>Saturday: 10am - 4pm</p>
      <p>Sunday: Closed</p>
      <p>Public Holidays: Closed</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, that works as in it shows underneath the right menu - but when I hover over it and hover over the drop down, the original menu (e.g Team, Solutions & Services) then loose their background (as the mouse isnt hovering over it anymore) but this didnt occur before either?

Comment: @llpo there is issue with menu hover..please fix this too..and m also working on this with other issue.

Comment: Yeah sorry that's because there's a gap between the dropdown and the title. One second I'll fix it.

Comment: Sorry @Ilpo, I've updated the code above to reflect the proper updates I made since the pastebin links >< I also included your edited CSS

Comment: @rawrjoelmalex please wait..as m done with html structure and css part..soon will update final ans..

Comment: @IlpoOksanen can you highlight what changes you made to fix it?

Comment: Got it @IlpoOksanen. Would you happen to know why my second problem exists of the floating?

Comment: I made some edits to clarify. What second problem are you referring to?

Comment: @rawrjoelmalex always use clear:both after float so there won't be any structure problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please copy and paste this code as m done with the help of LLpo Oksaned(li help).

**Updated:**

CSS :

```
/*
        Business Website
        Author: Joel Male;
        Date Started: 20/06/2015;
        Date Finished: **;
*/

/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        /////////// WEB STUFF //////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

@font-face {
        font-family: BebasFont;
        src: url("bebas-font.ttf");
}

/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        ////// HANDLE DEFAULT MARKUPS //////
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

body {
        background-color: #666;
        color: #000305;
        font-size: 87.5%;
        font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
        line-height: 1.5;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
}

a {
        text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {

}

a:hover, a:active {

}

/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        //// HANDLE HEADER/CONTAINER ///////
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

header {
        margin: 0 auto 10px; /* Centers the page */
        width: 100%;
        clear: both; /* Nothing floats on the page */
}

.content {
        width: 70%;
        margin: 0 auto;
}

/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        ////// HANDLE MAINHEADER HERE //////
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

.mainheader {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #022930;
        height: auto;
}

.mainheader nav {
        padding-top: 2%;
        height: 40px;
}

.mainheader nav h1 {
        color: white;
        font-family: 'BebasFont';
        margin-top: -12px;
        float: left;
        padding-left: 15%;
        font-size: 40px;
}

.mainheader nav ul {
        padding-right: 15%;
        float: right;
        padding-left: 0; /* THIS REMOVES THE PADDING BETWEEN NAV AND HOME */
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainheader nav ul li {
        font-family: 'BebasFont';
        position: relative;
        display: inline;
}

.mainheader nav ul li ul {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 160%;
}

.mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited {
        color: #FFF;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 25px;
        height: 20px;
}

.mainheader nav li:hover>a, .mainheader nav a:active,
.mainheader nav .active a:link, .mainheader nav .active a:visited {
        background-color: #CF5C3F;
        text-shadow: none;
}

.mainheader nav ul li a {
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainheader .subheader {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        display:flex;

}

.inner_header {
    width:66%;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.mainheader .subheader .left-content {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
}

.mainheader .subheader .left-content h1 {
        margin-top: 0;
        font-family: 'BebasFont';
        color: #FFF;
}

.mainheader .subheader .right-content{
        float:left;
        width:50%;

}

.mainheader .subheader .right-content img {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        float:right;
}

/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        //// HANDLE THE DROP DOWN MENUS ////
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

.mainheader nav ul li:hover ul {
        display: block; /* THIS SHOULD HANDLE THE SHOWING OF THE MENU */
        padding-right: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 27px;
        left: 0;
}


.mainheader nav ul ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #666;
}

.mainheader nav ul ul li {
        display: block;
        padding-right: 0;
        min-width: 178px;
}

.mainheader nav ul ul li:hover {
        background-color: #CF5C3F;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        //// HANDLE THE FIRST SECTION //////
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

.firstsection {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        line-height: 25px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.firstsection .firstarticle {
        background-color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 2% 0%;
        margin-top: 2.8%;
        height: 220px;
        background-color: #CCC; /* THIS CHANGES THE BACKGROUND COLOR OF THE TOP CONTENT BACKGROUND */
}

.firstsection .firstarticle .image-wrapper {
        width: 32%;
        padding-left: 2%;
        float: left;
}

.firstsection .firstarticle h1 {
        margin-top: 0;
}

.firstsection .firstarticle .leftcontent {
        width: 26%;
        float: left;
}

.firstsection .firstarticle .leftcontent a {
        color: #07bac1;
}

.firstsection .firstarticle .leftcontent a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
}

.firstsection .firstarticle .rightcontent {
        padding-right: 2%;
        width: 26%;
        float: right;
}

.firstsection .firstarticle .rightcontent img {
        padding-right: 3%;
}

.firstsection .firstarticle .rightcontent i {
        font-style: italic;
        color: #999;
        font-size: 85%;
}

/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        //////// HANDLE THE FOOTER /////////
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

.mainfooter {
        width: 100%;
        height: 140px;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        margin-top: 2%;
        background-color: #666;
        color: white;
}
.mainfooter a {
        color: #FFF;
}

.mainfooter .top-row {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 5px;
}

.mainfooter .top-row h1 {
        padding-top: 1%;
        padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.mainfooter .top-row .leftrow {
        padding-left: 15%;
        padding-top: 5%;
        float: left;
}

.mainfooter .top-row .right-leftside {
        width: 300px;
        float: right;
}

.mainfooter .top-row .right-rightside {
        width: 300px;
        padding-right: 7%;
        float: right;
}

/*
        ////////////////////////////////////
        /// HANDLE PHONE/SMALLER SCREENS ///
        ////////////////////////////////////
*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 600px)
{
        .body {
                width: 90%;
                font-size: 95%;
        }

        .mainheader img {
                width: 30%;
        }

        .mainheader nav {
                background: #666;
                height: 200px;
                line-height: 30px;
                margin-bottom: 0;
                border-radius: 5px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .mainheader nav ul {
                list-style: none;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding-left: 0;
        }

        .mainheader nav li {
                width: 100%;
                margin-left: 0 auto;
        }

        .mainheader nav a:link, .mainheader nav a:visited {
                color: #FFF;
                display: block;
                height: 30px;
                padding: 5px 0;
                text-decoration: none;
        }

        .mainheader nav a:active,
        .mainheader nav .active a:link, .mainheader nav .active a:visited {
                background: #CF5C3F;
                color: #fff;
                text-shadow: none !important;
        }

        .mainheader nav li a {
                border-radius: 5px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

                border-radius: 5px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;

                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .content {
                width: 100%;
                float: left;
                margin-top: 2%;
        }

        .top-content {
                background-color: #FFF;
                border-radius: 5px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                padding: 3% 5%;
                margin-top: 2%;
        }

        .bottom-content {
                background-color: #FFF;
                border-radius: 5px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                padding: 3% 5%;
                margin-top: 2px;
        }
}
```

and html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
                <title> Computer Company </title>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css" type="text/css" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
        <header>
                <div class="mainheader">
                        <nav>
                                <h1>Company</h1>
                                <ul>
                                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Solutions & Services</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Internet</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Networking</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Website</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Home Computers</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Servers</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Team</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Founder</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Graphics</a></li>
                                                </ul></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </nav>

                        <div class="subheader">
                            <div class="inner_header">
                                <div class="left-content">
                                        <h1>Hello!</h1>

                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="right-content">
                                        <img src="images/logo.jpg"/>
                                </div>
                                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                              </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
        </header>


<div class="content">

        <div class="firstsection">
                        <article class="firstarticle">
                                <div class="image-wrapper">
                                        <img src="images/computer.jpeg"/>
                                </div>
                                <content class="leftcontent">
                                        <h1>Efficient, Affordable, Reliable</h1>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi.</p>
                                        <p><a href="#">› Contact us</a></p>
                                </content>
                                <content class="rightcontent">
                                        <h1>Latest Feedback</h1>
                                        <p><img src="images/plus.gif"/>Solved my problem quickly and efficiently! <i>- Melissa, QLD</i></p>
                                        <p><img src="images/plus.gif"/>Called Joel to organize an appointment, he came over and fixed the problem the same day!<i>- Zac, QLD </i></p>
                                </content>
                        </article>
        </div>

</div>


<footer class="mainfooter">
        <div class="top-row">

                <p class="leftrow"> &copy; 2015 <a href="index.html">Computer Company</a></p>

                <div class="right-rightside">
                        <h1>Contact</h1>
                        <p>Joel Male @</p>
                        <p>Mobile</p>
                        <p>Email</p>
                </div>
                <div class="right-leftside">
                        <h1>Opening Hours</h1>
                        <p>Monday - Friday: 9am - 5pm</p>
                        <p>Saturday: 10am - 4pm</p>
                        <p>Sunday: Closed</p>
                        <p>Public Holidays: Closed</p>
                </div>
        </div>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please check this code and let me know still is there any issue..

Thank you..

Comment: Hi Leo, I accidentally submitted and old version of the code, please see my answer edit for the updated html/css (including Ilpo OKsanen's answer), but also includes the non working section code

Comment: This is my issue: http://i.imgur.com/ZXOCNN0.png
With this CSS code: http://pastebin.com/3qPNSAhT

I don't know why float: left; isn't making it go all the way to the left, even though the container is 100% screen width :(

Comment: @rawrjoelmalex i already solved that issue..you are giving padding thats why green section is visiable..still let me check.

Comment: Ah you fixed it? I wasn't sure as the HTML/CSS you edited was actually an older version :(

Comment: My inspect element doesn't show any padding to the left or right :(

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/IP0Y9RA.png

This is what it looks like removing all left padding (it should be all the way on the left side of the screen to start, since float: left) but it's not working :/

Comment: i tried with this css http://pastebin.com/3qPNSAhT and all structure got disturbed..but you need hello + blog image under the header but not in content div..right?

Comment: and there is no hello in your html part..please check your html and css which you gave in question..

Comment: Sorry, it's all messy the code i've posted :( http://pastebin.com/847DHkVX This is the HTML as of current. I need hello aligned to left, blog image to right, both under the nav (so under the COMPANY and navigation bar)

Comment: the line, yes i did! it works perfectly. I think i need to research your code so i can learn what it does, specifically the "float: flex" thank you!

Comment: then please accept this as answer and upvote my answer so other can take help..ty and if you need then i can tell you tag's(like float, clear) working in details..ty

Comment: Negative marks giver..can you please come on my face and tell me what wrong in it?

Comment: I can't give 2 answers to one question, and the other guy helped me the most so I gave him the answer. I didn't say anything was wrong with your answer.

Comment: @rawrjoelmalex, sorry but this comment wasnt for you..there is other guy who gave me negative point to my answer so..it was for him.